# Regex negative lookbehind matching excluded items

Tags: python, regex

I am having difficulty understanding this expression:

```
/((?<!=0)x2)/
```

While trying to match "x2" on string of "0x2 - 2x = 1"

The goal is to look behind of "x2" and check if it is a "0" and then avoid selecting it.
If it is just "x2" then I want it selected. (For example string "x2 - 3x = 4")

I have tried it both ways with positive/negative lookahead/behinds and it always keeps matching the zero (0).

Could anyone give some insight into why this might be happening?

I am using https://regex101.com/ to test it (With Python option selected).

Am I right when I assume that:

```
?<!=
```

Means that the following symbols need to be excluded if they are located BEFORE the actual match exp?

Comment: try `/((?<!0)x2)/`

Comment: Oh wow, it was about to drive me crazy... everywhere on the web the lookbehind has an equals as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues the format used here is for javascript and not for python, you do not need leading/trailing `/`

```
/((?<!=0)x2)/
```

We get to

```
((?<!=0)x2)
```

Understanding look arounds

```
              Positive  Negative
Look ahead    (?=       (?!
Look Behind   (?<=      (?<!
```

So we get to

```
((?<!0)x2)
```

And then there is still some redundancy of surrounding (), you need it to separate groups within a full match, so simplify it

```
(?<!0)x2
```

Working demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/lIA3vH/1).

Comment: Thanks mate, this grouping was neccesary for my current goal so it was intentional, anyway, I will accept your anwser in a few minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

> If it is just "**x2**" then I want it selected

In case if `x2` considered to be a separate substring - use the following regex pattern:

```
(?!<0)\b(x2)
```

https://regex101.com/r/jpEviL/3

Answer (score 0):

You are close; however, in Python, the negative lookbehind is simply `?<!` , with no `=`:

```
import re
s = "0x2 - 2x = 1"
if re.findall("(?<!0)x2", s):
   print("no zero as a coefficient")
else:
   print('found zero as coefficient')
```